# How to Prevent Conflict between BTsync and IPython-notebook?

Tags: 14.04, ipython, btsync

System: Ubuntu 14.04, IPython 2.

Both opens the connection to `127.0.0.1:8888` which causes a lot of problems. If such a conflict happen, BTsync create a second instance of its files. This causes duplicate files and directories. 
This thread has been forwarded to the developers of BTsync, since their program did not check the existence of the connection. Their program also create falsely duplicates complicating the three. I think this is a bug in BTsync.

---

How can you Prevent Conflict between BTsync and IPython-Notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from support of BTsync

```
Sync has ability to configurate network settings such as port using configuration file. You can find more info regarding it here:

http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/204762689

The option you are looking for is located in webui section
"listen" : <IP: port>
For example, 0.0.0.0:4444 will listen to any interface on the LAN at port 4444.
```

So specify the port to something specific to avoid collisions.